# How to use factories with Ionic/Angular JS with phonegap?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm trying use global variables in my ionic/angular + phonegap app project by using factory service.

However, adding even a simple factory service like the one below messes up the app somehow & all screens of the app become pure white.

```
.factory('serviceName', function() {
    return {}
})
```

I've 2 js files named `app.js` & `controller.js`

app.js looks like this with much more states:

```
// Ionic Starter App
// angular.module is a global place for creating, registering and retrieving Angular modules
// 'starter' is the name of this angular module example (also set in a <body> attribute in index.html)
// the 2nd parameter is an array of 'requires'
// 'starter.controllers' is found in controllers.js
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers'])

//TRIED ADDING FACTORY HERE

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);

    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('app', {
    url: '/app',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/menu.html',
    controller: 'AppCtrl'
  });
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/playlists');
});
```

My `controller.js` somewhat looks like this with much more variables & functions:

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])


//ALSO TRIED ADDING FACTORY HERE

.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $ionicModal, $timeout,$http) {

  // With the new view caching in Ionic, Controllers are only called
  // when they are recreated or on app start, instead of every page change.
  // To listen for when this page is active (for example, to refresh data),
  // listen for the $ionicView.enter event:
  //$scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function(e) {
  //});

  // Form data for the login modal
  $scope.loginData = {};
})


.controller('PlaylistsCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.playlists = [
    { title: 'Reggae', id: 1 },
    { title: 'Chill', id: 2 },
    { title: 'Dubstep', id: 3 },
    { title: 'Indie', id: 4 },
    { title: 'Rap', id: 5 },
    { title: 'Cowbell', id: 6 }
  ];
})

.controller('PlaylistCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams) {
})
```

I referred this http://mcgivery.com/ionic-using-factories-and-web-services-for-dynamic-data/ to start using factories.

I know can use $rootScope but it has all the [problems of global variables](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad), so please help me use factories. Also, if someone can give me debugging tips with phonegap. I use the phonegap development app on android and keep an eye on the console while working with it.

Comment: Where did you create the factory in your code? make sure its included properly, it might be throwing `error: factory not found` check the console

Comment: I'll just edit & put it in the code.

Comment: Give us some error messages or something, or better give a demo in code pen http://codepen.io/ionic/pen/hqcju

Comment: need your exact code to see what happen. `//ALSO TRIED ADDING FACTORY HERE` won't help any.

Comment: Where is the state definition corresponding to `/app/playlists` url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[factory](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers)** in your app like this:

```
.factory("serviceName", function() {
    var playlists = [{
        title: 'Reggae',
        id: 1
    }, {
        title: 'Chill',
        id: 2
    }, {
        title: 'Dubstep',
        id: 3
    }, {
        title: 'Indie',
        id: 4
    }, {
        title: 'Rap',
        id: 5
    }, {
        title: 'Cowbell',
        id: 6
    }];

    var _myVariableValue = 123;

    return {
        myPlayList: function() {
            return playlists;
        },
        getValue: function() {
            return _myVariableValue;
        }
    };
})
```

and call in your **[controller](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller)**

```
.controller('PlaylistsCtrl', function($scope, serviceName) { 
    $scope.playlists =  serviceName.myPlayList();
    $scope.myvariablevalue =  serviceName.getValue();    
})
```