# how to add a factory in ionic?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

i'm experimenting with ionic (and building using phonegap online builder) and i'm trying to add a factory now but it messes up and gives a blank white screen. i tried the fix in a similar problem : [How to use factories with Ionic/Angular JS with phonegap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35170294/how-to-use-factories-with-ionic-angular-js-with-phonegap)

but it still doesnt work. my services.js file looks like this:

```
.factory('userFactory', [function() {
var users = [
    {name: 'Omar', city: 'rizal'},
    {name: 'Ganny', city: 'makati'},
    {name: 'Chester', city: 'manila'}
];
return {
    getUsers: function(){
        return users;
        },
    getUser: function(id){
        for(i=0;i<users.length;i++){
            if(users[i].name == id)
            {
                return users[i];
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
};
}])
```

and my controller looks like this:

```
angular.module('app.controllers', [])

.controller('CityCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$location'
function ($scope, $stateParams, $location, userFactory) {
 $scope.userdata = {};
 $scope.enterCity = function(usern,city) {
    if(userFactory.getUser(usern) != null)
    {
        $location.path('/page14');
    }
    else
    {
        alert('Failed');
    }
}

}])
```

Comment: your `users` array doesn't have any objects with a `Username` property, so `getUser()` is **always** going to return `null`.

Comment: thanks, i did not see that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your depdencenies to the controller is not properly formated,It should be

```
.controller('CityCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$location','userFactory',
function ($scope, $stateParams, $location, userFactory) {
```